# What is the difference between Responce.Redirect and Response.RedirectLocation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

If I redirect a page using `Response.RedirectLocation ="login.aspx"` then how it is different form `Responce.Redirect("~/login.aspx")`?
Thanks

Comment: RedirectLocation just sets the location header. Redirect
sets the header, sets the correct status code, includes a quick
snippet of HTML saying that the resource has moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RedirectLocation` sets the `Location` HTTP header. `Redirect` does so much more and completes the response with a 3xx status code.

Answer (score 4):

`Response.Redirect(url);` Causes a 302 redirect (A temporary redirect) and closes the response causing the user browser to be redirected to the alternative URL.

If you want to permanently update a URL, for example you have made changes in the URL structure and you wish to let the world know that this is a permanent change (ie. search engines to pass on the ranking from the old URL to the new), then this should be indicated via a **301 Permanent Redirect**.

This can be done as follows:

```
  Response.Status = "301 Permanent Redirect";
  Response.StatusCode = 301;
  Response.RedirectLocation = "http://newurl.com/";
  Response.End();
```

Note: `Response.RedirectLocation` does not stop processing of preceding code (unlike `Response.Redirect()`). This means that unless you want to continue processing tasks, you need to close the connection.

**To summarise:**

Response.Redirect() always causes a 302 temporary redirect, and halts processing

Response.RedirectLocation allows more control, for example setting the correct status codes, or continue further processing if required.